# How to convert string to timestamp into bigquery

Tags: date, select, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, timestamp

I have a BQ stage table with a string column that holds timestamp format like below:

```
2000-01-01 00:00:00.0000000 -08:00
2010-10-01 00:00:00.0000000 -07:00
```

How to load this strings into another BQ table which has timestamp as type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Canonical form of timestamp is `YYYY-[M]M-[D]D[( |T)[H]H:[M]M:[S]S[.DDDDDD]][time zone]` and can consist only up to six fractional digits (microsecond precision)

So, in case you data actually has 6 (not seven) digits - you can use either of below

```
PARSE_TIMESTAMP('%F %H:%M:%E6S %Ez', ts)
```

OR

```
PARSE_TIMESTAMP('%F %H:%M:%E*S %Ez', ts)
```

Comment: Thanks @Mikhail I can limit the 7 digits to 6 digits. Now when Im using                  
"select PARSE_TIMESTAMP('%F %H:%M:%E*S %Ez',"2000-01-01 06:30:11.000000 -08:00" ) "  , I am gettting the output as -  
2000-01-01 14:30:11 UTC.   I was expecting it to be 2000-01-01 06:30:11.000000 UTC kind of.. am I missing something here..

Comment: you asked how to covert string to timestamp - you got it - while your expectations might were not 100% correct

Comment: quick question. how to handle this ( |T) in parse_timestamp

Answer (score 0):

Your string looks like a legitimate literal timestamp string, so doesn't `cast()` just work?

```
cast(my_string_col as timestamp) my_timestamp_col
```

Otherwise, you need `parse_timestamp()`:

```
parse_timestamp(''%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%E#7 %Ez', my_string_col) my_timestamp_col
```